What is the proper name of the "layered" sequencer in Roland Fantom series?
Complete beginner here.
I saw a demo of Roland Phantom-0x and usage of its sequencer (?) -- a person played for example some drums on a keyboard (I am not talking about numpad), it was recorded by Fantom. Then it was played back and the person played for example piano as separate layer. If player made a mistake, the recording could be deleted. Then both tracks (drums+piano) could be played back, and on top of this could be added layer of guitar. And so forth, layer by layer, single person could recreate entire piece like a full band (minus the voice). What's more, layers length could be different -- for example layer K could be very short, so it was possible to loop it.
I searched in the music store for phrase "sequencer" and then searched on YT to view some demos, but either I was out of luck, or the demos were more focused on numpad of the sequencer and providing drum beat from it.
So is it "just" sequencer in Fantom series, or is it separate category -- "layered" sequencer? (I am looking for proper name of course).
I am interested in hardware device, not program for computer. I have an old Yamaha keyboard which has MIDI in+out connections so I though that maybe I could buy such layered sequencer, connect it and at moderate price have more fun. Assuming that if I play violin on my keyboard sequencer is able to store the info about the instrument and then played it back correctly.

It is simply a multi track sequencer (pretty much all sequencers are multi track). What you call layers are more typically called tracks, say drum, bass, piano, etc. tracks. Sometimes they have a limited number of tracks that you can record, say 16 or they might have many more. I don’t know if there are very many stand alone sequencers available anymore but there must be some. They were very popular when MIDI first came out and before digital audio recording became available. Now MIDI recording is more commonly done with computers, software (many are free) and a MIDI interface to a computer.

When looking for a sequencer to connect to your keyboard, you’ll probably only find ones that have pads on them (what you’re calling “number keys”). Don’t worry about that. Those kinds of sequencers can still record and playback your keyboard performances. The pads usually both allow you to trigger sounds and note and also control the sequencing, so you need them anyway.

@JohnBelzaguy many thanks. If you could repost your comment as an answer, I could mark it as a solution of my question. Thank you in advance.

@greenoldman I posted and expanded a bit. Good luck to you!

It is simply a multi track sequencer (pretty much all sequencers are multi track). What you call layers are more typically called tracks, say drum, bass, piano, etc. tracks. Sometimes they have a limited number of tracks that you can record, say 16 or they might have many more. There are some standalone sequencers available today. Some of them combine internal sounds such as drums with sequencing and some are combination sequencers and samplers. They were very popular when MIDI first came out and before digital audio recording became available. Now MIDI recording is more commonly done with computers, software (many are free) and a MIDI interface to a computer. Some things to keep in mind are price point and the ability of your keyboard to play multiple sounds at once (multitimbral). If you have a computer you can get a DAW, or digital audio workstation (some are free, like Apple’s Garageband) and an inexpensive MIDI interface and it may actually be cheaper than an actual sequencer.

Thank you very much for the expansion. Maybe I explain my remark about computer -- of course price is a factor, but I would like to use "real" hardware to get detached from a computer, for mental hygiene. I am "a bit" saturated of computer usage :-).

@greenoldman I can appreciate that. In that case as long as your keyboard is multitimbral you can layer parts by assigning individual sounds to different MIDI channels. You can probably get up to 16. You might also find a good deal on a used sequencer.

The sequencer has four stages - track, which speaks for itself, and holds the patterns. Pattern which is the recorded performance data. Each track can hold 8 patterns. Group which is the term for parts like verse, chorus, etc. Group 1 may be the intro, for example. And finally song, which plays back your groups in the arrangement you made. Each song can be saved in a scene which can be exported as a MIDI file, if needed.
Those are the 'official' Roland terms.
